# Vaadin7.1.15 on Google App Engine using Eclipse Kepler - web.xml missing

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, vaadin

I am trying to create a Vaadin Application and deploy it to Google App Engine.
I found some tutorials which seem to be not up to date anymore:

For example this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTAK-NGs9ng

Wen I create a Project using **Vaadin7 Project** template in Ecplise - Eclipse and enable Google App Engine for this project Eclipse still refuses to deploy the application with the message

```
Could not locate D:\Vaadin\GoogleAppVaadin7Project\war\WEB-INF\web.xml
```

How should the web.xml of a hello-world project look like?

Comment: I build an vaadin apllication a few day ago and I deployed it in AppEngine container without problem following this tutorial  [How to build an AppEngine project] (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven)

Comment: Its about Vaadin application, Skizzo!